# getElementById() not working input type time

Tags: javascript, html

Why the code below does not return a value?

```
<input type="time" id="hora" style="margin: 0 auto;" class="button button-block button-stable">
```

JS:

```
var hora = document.getElementById('hora').innerHTML; 
console.log(hora);
```

Print " "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why the code below does not return a value?

Because input elements don't have `innerHTML`, they have `value`:

```
var hora = document.getElementById('hora').value; 
console.log(hora);
```